Making a Container height match the Intrinsic Row Height inside a ListView
I want to make the container height to match the Row height inside this ListView, so I get a nice indicator for every card. The column will have variable length, so I cannot set a specific height. If I try to use Expanded widget, IntrinsicHeight widget or "height: double.infinity" I will get rendering exceptions.
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 10,
                    //height: 50,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('A\nB\nC\nD'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('$index'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}


You can wrap your entire Row inside IntrinsicHeight Widget as follows:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 10,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    const Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('A\nB\nC\nD'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('$index'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

And remove the height from the container, this will make the container take the full height of the card, this will be the result:


I was using IntrinsicHeight in the wrong part of the widgets tree. Thanks.
